# Positioning error on IndoorAtlas

Tags: indoor-positioning-system

I registered my building map to IndoorAtlas, and I had measured a data for a map, and opened it as public.  (using IndoorAtras official android app)

And building map is appeared in public map..

But when positioning mode is started, this error message is popup-ed and positioning function is not started.

[Positioning errer : Connection to positioning service could not be established]

My phone has a 3G network service and connected wifi as well.
No internet connection problem too.

What is a reason and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please contact IndoorAtlas support@indooratlas.com with your account details / floorplanID so we can check further what might be the issue. Thanks!

Elina